# Azure Active Directory user roles and authorization

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, user-roles

I have application hosted on Azure, Angular 4 on front and .net core 2.0 on back-end. 
What I want to achieve is: To add Roles to my users who are added to my Azure Active Directory. 
Authentication is implemented and works well. I use ADAL and I send my bearer token with every request.

1. These are my app roles defined in the manifest on azure portal:

   ```
   "appRoles": [
   {
     "allowedMemberTypes": [
       "User"
     ],
     "displayName": "Reviewer",
     "id": "0238c2bb-9857-4d07-b760-a47ec621d57a",
     "isEnabled": true,
     "description": "Reviewer only have the ability to view tasks and their statuses.",
     "value": "Reviewer"
   },
   {
     "allowedMemberTypes": [
       "User"
     ],
     "displayName": "Approver",
     "id": "000018cb-19e3-4f89-bf99-5d7acf30773b",
     "isEnabled": true,
     "description": "Approvers have the ability to change the status of tasks.",
     "value": "Approver"
   }
   ```

   ]
2. Approver role is assigned to the desired user.
3. I send request to the back-end (.net core 2.0 web api) where I have [Authorize] attribute and I check the user claims **User.Claims.ToList()** then I recieve that the user is approver:

> [15]{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role:
>   Approver}

And that's great!

4. Now I add policy in startup.cs

   ```
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
   {
       options.AddPolicy("ElevatedRights", policy =>
         policy.RequireRole("Approver"));
   });
   ```
5. Then this is the step where the problem happens. I add the following code in the controller (see step 3). I change the [Authorize] method with
   `[Authorize(Policy = "ElevatedRights")]`
   but I got rejected then. I even tried with `[Authorize(Roles = "Approver")]`

What do I miss or do wrong?

P.S. Feel free to suggest better title for the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's necessary in this case, but have you specified the `RoleClaimsType` on your `AddJwtBearer` call? Something like: `AddJwtBearer(o => o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role })`. Instead of `ClaimTypes.Role`, you can also try `"roles"`.

Comment: Hmm tnx for your answer @juunas I'll try right now and see if something changes

Comment: It's same like before...

Comment: The test looks like this in the source code: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/Infrastructure/RolesAuthorizationRequirement.cs#L57. So the problem should be related to it not realizing what the user's roles are. You might be able to instead use `RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Approver")`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you. You can write answer if you want right away :) p.s I'll try without the code from your first comment now and let you know if it should be there.

Comment: Oh actually I have that code in my configuration.
options.TokenValidationParameters = new 
         TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    RoleClaimType = "roles",
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it does not know which claim to map the roles to.

You might be able to instead use `RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Approver")`.

Another possible way (which should work) is to specify the `RoleClaimsType` on your `AddJwtBearer` call. Something like:

```
AddJwtBearer(o => o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role })`.
```

Instead of `ClaimTypes.Role`, you can also try `"roles"`.